# Flutter modify outer variable within a stream callback

Tags: flutter, scope, stream

I'm trying to write a function that would only return one event from a stream when it's being called.

```
AccelerometerEvent getOneAclmtrEvent() {
    AccelerometerEvent aclmtr;
    StreamSubscription<AccelerometerEvent> sub;
    sub = accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
        aclmtr = event;
        sub.cancel();
        debugPrint("Inside Stream: " + aclmtr.toString());
    });
    debugPrint("Outside Stream: " + aclmtr.toString());
    return aclmtr;
}
```

However, it seems that the variable `aclmtr` I declare outside of the stream, would not have its value set within the stream callback.

The output:

```
I/flutter ( 6218): Inside Stream: [AccelerometerEvent (x: -0.009969456121325493, y: 0.041620802134275436, z: 9.975326538085938)]
I/flutter ( 6218): Outside Stream: null
```

It seems that the variable `aclmtr` was created a local copy within the stream, what would be the best way to modify a variable (or rather, return the desired value) from within a stream?

Comment: `"I'm trying to write a function that would only return one event from a stream when it's being called."` - so use `Stream.first` (the docs say: *"The first element of this stream."*) or i am missing something?

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much, `Stream.first` is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: sure, your welcome